# Sync adapter not working on Cynogenmod

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have created Sync adapter for one of my application on android. I am able to see it working on android devices (verified on 4.4 and 5.1). But same is not working with cynogenmod (tried on one plus one). Basically I dont see "onPerformSync" function getting called unless I go to account and manually sync it.

Is there any other setting or permissions we need to set to run it on cynogenmod? I dont see AutoSync option either in Accounts menu. Is it something related this? Does cynogen support auto sync?